# understanding fs/binfmt_elf.c

Tags: c, linux

i am trying to understand the linux source file **/home/akash/Downloads/linux-3.4.3/fs/binfmt_elf.c**  a part a code is as follows where i hv stuck.

```
static struct linux_binfmt elf_format = {
        .module         = THIS_MODULE,
        .load_binary    = load_elf_binary,
        .load_shlib     = load_elf_library,
        .core_dump      = elf_core_dump,
        .min_coredump   = ELF_EXEC_PAGESIZE,
};
```

which refer to the file **include/linux/binfmt.h**

```
struct linux_binfmt {
        struct list_head lh;
        struct module *module;
        int (*load_binary)(struct linux_binprm *, struct  pt_regs * regs);
        int (*load_shlib)(struct file *);
        int (*core_dump)(struct coredump_params *cprm);
        unsigned long min_coredump;     /* minimal dump size */
};
```

plz giv some explaination on this..

Comment: You need explanation on the struct initialization?

Answer (score 5):

It is the initialisation of a structure of type `struct linux_binfmt` named `elf_format` (with `static` storage duration, meaning it exists for the lifetime of the program and is initialised exactly once), using syntax introduced in C99 that allows the specific structure member being initialised to be specified. Prior to C99 the initializer of a `struct` required the values to be listed in the order the members are declared in the `struct`.

For example:

```
struct struct_a { int a; char c; };
```

In C89 it was not possible to explicitly initialise `c` only:

```
struct struct_a s = { 0, 'f' }; /* Have to provide an initial value for
                                   'a', the 0, in order to provide an
                                   initial value for 'c', the f. */
```

but in C99 the new syntax made it possible:

```
struct struct_a s = { .c = 'f' };
```

The types of `struct` members:

- `lh` is of type `struct list_head`, which is not explicitly initialised. `lh` will be default initialised (any members of `lh` that are pointers are initialized to a null pointer and any arithmetic types will be initialized to zero).
- `module` is of type `struct module*` and is initialised to `THIS_MODULE`.
- `load_binary` is a pointer to a function that returns an `int` and takes arguments of type `struct linux_binptrm*` and `struct pt_regs`, and is initialised to a function called `load_elf_binary`.
- `load_shlib` is a pointer to a function that returns an `int` and takes an argument of type `struct file*` and is initialised to a function called `load_elf_library`.
- `core_dump` is a pointer to a function that returns an `int` and takes an argument of `struct coredump_params*` and is initialised to a function called `elf_core_dump`.
- `min_coredump` is of type `unsigned long` and is initialised to `ELF_EXEC_PAGESIZE`.

Refer to section *6.7.8 Initialization* of the C99 standard for a full description on initialization syntax and rules.

Answer (score 0):

`elf_format` is a variable of type `linux_binfmt` declared as static.

Values assigned for the members of `elf_format`

```
    .module         = THIS_MODULE,
    .load_binary    = load_elf_binary,    /* Function pointer assigned with functions */
    .load_shlib     = load_elf_library,   // do --
    .core_dump      = elf_core_dump,      // do --
    .min_coredump   = ELF_EXEC_PAGESIZE,
```